# Laravel post route error

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, http-post, laravel-routing

I searched in many threads but any can't solve my problem.

I use XAMPP (LAMPP on Lubuntu 15.10) as server. I create a new project with:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel angulara`

I add a new route in `app/HTTP/routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::any('/test', function($check = 'OK'){
    return 'Check: '.$check;
});
```

I use curl to send request and get respond. When I use `curl -X "GET" http://localhost/test`, I get the respond `Check: OK`. But when I use `curl -X "POST" http://localhost/test`, I get the respond:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1 TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:
in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

I'm new to Laravel so I don't know, where to look for errors and I'm learning with http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-5-angularjs-tutorial so I need post request by $HTTP method from AngularJS.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'ts Csrf token issue.
You can't use post method without "_token" variable or else you modify the routes code.You can get the token but this method:

```
<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>
```

Or you can have it in your form like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Check out Laravel docs [CSRF Protection](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection).

And then just go to the `Kernel.php` file (app/Http/Kernel.php) and disable `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware.

```
 **
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    //\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];
```

Comment: The token provides cross site access protection. Bad practice to disable it. Just use {{crsf_field() }} somewhere in your form.

Comment: @TimvanUum Yep, but when @Thomas Sablik use `curl` to send request, I think we just have only 1 way to solve this by disable `VerifyCsrfToken`